# Как спарсить и отформатировать в docx? C#

Tags: c#

На вход кладу файл .txt который выглядит так:

```
:61:230413D15546178,2S10349677328//6391965194
GOD/
:61:230413C333000,S202102674830882//6388156197
NCCMM/RTRN FNDS
:61:230413C952168,99S202PTCN2S2300288441//6391858000
RFND B/O 
:61:230413C6000000,S103WSLID234C0005TYZ//6390105971
:61:230413C17120000,S202102674833140//6391866680
NCCBBMM/RTRN FNDS
```

Ниже, то что хочу получить отформатированным в docx:

```
 61: Statement Line 
            Value  Entr F Code Reference                      Amount        Ma 
            230406        S103 49636932                         #20,#       D 
                               6359058720 
            230406        S103 49637251                         #10,#       D 
                               6359083606 
            230406        S103 49637055                         #10,#       D 
                               6359058833 
            230406        S103 49636292                         #10,#       D 
                               6358231853 
            230406        S103 49636207                         #30,#       D 
                               6358387897 
            230406        S103 49636423                         #50,#       D 
                               GOD/ 
            230406        S103 49630932                    #1070079,28#     D 
                               6358895735 
                               STR/ 
            230406        S103 MTT230415KO77055            #1245400,#       C 
                               6355807094 
            230406        S202 102064702221               #163443050,#       C 
                               6358276861 
                               NCCTTBMM/RTRN FNDS
```

Код который используя для нахождения в файле строку :61: и записи в файл. Создал шаблон где меняется с TES2608T на нужное значение

```cs
bool foundLineWith61 = false;
if (line.StartsWith(":61:"))
{   
    linesWith61.Add(line);
    replacements.Add(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(":61:") + 4));
    foundLineWith61 = true;
}

for (int i = 0; i < linesWith61.Count; i++)
{
    string allReplacements = string.Join("\r\n", replacements.Select(x => $"{x}"));
    ReplaceText(doc, "TES2608T", allReplacements,true);
}
```

А это то, что сейчас получаю. Как можно привести в отформатированный вариант выше?

[image: Конечный файл]

```
вот пример на одной строке:
:61:230816D93600,S10350385220//6888826916 

:61: 230816 D    93600, S103            50385220//6888826916
     Дата   D/C  СУММА  Sтри_символа    референс1//референс2

получить на выходе:
61: Statement Line 
            Value  Entr F Code Reference                      Amount        Ma 
            230816        S103 50385220                         #93600#       D 
                               6888826916
```

Comment: Что значит "отформатировать"? docx это отформатированный текст. и он в формате XML, а не то что вы показываете. А вообще для парсинга ткого текста подойдёт регулярное выражение. К сожалению, нет понимания, как именно и по каким правилам получается из исходного текста конечный, вы ничего не объяснили. Поэтому что-то конкретное здесь будет ответить проблематично.

Comment: [Open-Xml-PowerTools](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools), [Open-Xml-PowerTools Developer Center](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/open-xml-powertools-developer-center), [примеры использования](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools/tree/vNext/OpenXmlPowerToolsExamples).

Comment: @aepot под форматированием подразумевал приведение к определенному внешнему виду. Добавил объяснение на одной строке, что хочу получить